# Authentication with TeamForge/Collab.net using a self-signed SSL certificate and SVNKit

Tags: authentication, openssl, svnkit, collabnet, teamforge

I'm currently working on a project to automate checking in files to a Subversion repository hosted with TeamForge/Collab.net. I'm using SVNKit to handle the interactions between this program and the repository. Here's the relevant Java pieces I'm using for authentication:

```
SVNURL url = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("https://blah.collab.net/svn/repos");
ISVNAuthenticationManager mAuthManager = new BasicAuthenticationManager(new SVNAuthentication[]{
    SVNSSLAuthentication.newInstance(new File(certFilePath), certFilePassPhrase, true, url, false),
    SVNPasswordAuthentication.newInstance(login, passCharArray, false, url, false);
});
```

I generated the self-signed certificate using the following OpenSSL commands:

```
//generating a key and self-signed certificate
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out cert.crt -subj "/CN=svn.example.com"

//extracting public key from cert.crt
openssl x509 -in cert.crt -pubkey -noout
```

I've placed the public key in the "Authorization Keys" tab under my profile on TeamForge. In SVNKit, I'm specifying the cerFilePath as "path/to/cert.crt" and the certFilePassPhrase to be the same as used when creating the self-signed certificate.

Thus far, certificate authentication has always failed and fallen back onto the login/password, where I have the user manually inputting that information into the console on runtime. So the program is allowed to work, but I wouldn't be able to automate/schedule it without storing those user credentials.

What is the proper configuration of an SSL certificate with TeamForge? Am I generating my self-signed one correctly?

Comment: ***`CN=svn.example.com`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.